# empty array after setting a value from for-loop [index 0 is out of bounds, array size is 0.] [pine script]

Tags: arrays, for-loop, pine-script, dynamic-arrays

```
f_validtrends(_level_idx, _mode) =>
    array_idx = array.new_int(0)
    array_angle = array.new_float(0)

    [idx, angle] = for _i = array.size(_level_idx)-1 to 1
        delta_val = high[array.get(_level_idx, _i+1)]-high[array.get(_level_idx, _i)]
        delta_idx = f_idx_delta(_level_idx, _i, _i+1)
        angle = delta_val/delta_idx
        
        [int(_i), angle]
    array.push(array_idx, idx)
    array.push(array_angle, angle)
            
    [array_idx, array_angle]
    
    
[trend_high_idx, trend_high_angle] = f_validtrends(level_high_idx, 'high')
```

I have a problem with the function above. When I push values, which are originate from the for loop, onto the array, the array gets "corrupted". When trying to access the array(s) after array.push I get "`index 0  is out of bounds, array size is 0.`"

I've tried to instantiate the arrays on global scope, rewrote the for-loop, used `array.set` instead of `array.push`. When I use `array.push(array_idx, 10)` it all works as expected. Any suggestions / pointers?

Comment: is _level_idx non consecutive bar indices? If it is consecutive, using arrays might not be necessary. Also your array.push() statements should be part of the loop, making the tuple unnecessary. Other than that, most commonly you get this kind of oob error on the first bar when calling the function while _level_idx is empty. You could test this by nesting the loop in an if statement. if array.size(_level_idx) > 1

Comment: _level_idx is an array of ints with bar-indices of filtered pivot points. Initially I had the function without the tuple and indeed the push nested in the for-loop; not understanding the problem I moved the code in the function around. I'll try adding the if statement, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That's probably it. Most likely no pivots occur until at least a few bars in. Prior to that the index array would be empty and generate that error. You could also try using a fixed size array (do you really need to store every one?) and unshift/pop each new pivot occurrence. Initially it will be all na values then and also prevent this error

Comment: @rumpypumpydumpy I moved the function call in ```if barstate.islast``` Works flawlessly now. Thanks for your suggestions / feedback.